# Process unexpectedly exit. AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed problem

Tags: android

I Have some issues in my first android (KOTLIN) project that shows the following error.

```
Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2- 
3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

how to solve this problem. These problems are coming after the upgrade my android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'` to classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` or below `3.3.2`

I got the answer from this website : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/aapt2-daemon-startup-failed/32358

Comment: It will work but gives "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0."