# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0 ? When I downgraded gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I was not able to build a new project with gradle version 3.4.2 which was giving below error

**com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2- 
3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue 
if it does.**

I have searched stackoverflow and found the below answer

**Please degrade gradle to 3.3.2, I had degrade to 3.3.2 then its working. But it is not the right solution.**
[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359617/process-unexpectedly-exit-aapt2-aapt2-3-4-2-5326820-windows-daemon-0-daemon-s/57359646#comment101270462_57359646) [Reference 2](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/aapt2-daemon-startup-failed/32358/3)

After degrading gradle version from 3.4.2 to 3.3.2, Build was successful but it was giving below warning

**Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings**

Any help will be appreciated.